# program functions in dynamic loadable modules

Tags: c

Hello I am writing a program and dynamic loadable modules. Those modules are loaded using 'dlopen'. How do I use a program function in the module? Are function pointers the right way? Thank you

Comment: function pointers are the only way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Program needs to be linked with `-rdynamic` option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need function pointers and have to call [dlsym()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) to get them